# Regular Expression to return when invalid character found

Tags: sql, regex

I have the following regex that checks for a list of valid characters:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9+?/:().,' -]){1,35}$
```

What I now need to do now is search for any existing columns in our DB that invalidates the above regex. I'm using the oracle SQL `REGEXP_LIKE` command.

The problem I have is I can't seem to negate the above expression and return a value when it finds a character not in the expression e.g.

`"a-valid-filename.xml"` => this shouldn't be returned as it's valid.
`"an_invalid-filename.xml"` => I need to find these i.e. anything with an invalid character.

The obvious answer to me is to define a list of invalid characters... but that could be a long list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match it against the following regex which uses the `[^...]` negation character class:

```
([^a-zA-Z0-9+?/:().,' -])
```

This will match any single character that is not part of the list of characters that are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can negate a character class by inserting a caret as the first character.

Example:

```
[^y]
```

The above will match anything that is not `y`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
where not regexp_like(col, '^([a-zA-Z0-9+?/:().,'' -]){1,35}$')
```

or

```
where regexp_like(col, '[^a-zA-Z0-9+?/:().,'' -]')
```